# css size fix needed, please

Tags: html, css, size

i am trying to make a menu of sorts.

the code is available here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Chumillas/WyA3U/
(thank you Chumillas for teaching me about this)

if you check the result via the link above, you will see that there is a design issue with this code - all visible menu items have to have the same length (75px) **and this does not look beautify as the distances between them are uneven**:

```
.titleCell
{
    width: 75px;
```

how can i fix it so that the length is actually that of the content (+padding) instead of having to fix it to 75px so that **the distances between the menu items are THE SAME**?

- edit --

if it can not be done, i would be happy with a link to a similar thing online. thnx again

- edit 2 --

if anyone wonders where i got this thing originally from: http://www.devinrolsen.com/css-hide-and-display-content/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Chumillas/WyA3U/ I post it for you, get used to attach this type of things to your questions

Comment: wow. AWESOME tool. thank you so much for the effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `position:absolute` from `.titleCell strong` and change the `padding-left` to `padding-right` with a bigger value, something such as `40px`. Also remove the `width` from `.titleCell`

Here a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/

As an advise, don't apply rules for `strong` tag. Style the parent `div` or the parent `li`.

Comment: thank you that works exactly. i was stuck on this. now i can try and fix the other issues as well (strong, etc...). thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Although you've accepted an answer already I've made an update to your Fiddle with some layout fixes you might want to implement.

Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/WyA3U/3/

Answer (score 0):

[My two cents](http://jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/3/) — cleaner/less of both worlds:

```css
#contentBox { position: relative; font-size: 80%; }
#contentBox > li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#contentBox > li:hover, #contentBox ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#contentBox > li:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
}
#contentBox > li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
}
#contentBox ul
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 6px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="contentBox">
    <li>
        Go
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>
                    Quickly jump to your desired location
                </h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Messages
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>
                    Access personal and system messages and alerts
                </h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Assets
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>
                    Manage your assets
                </h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Support
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>
                    Need help?
                </h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: much cleaner, yes - but already made a bunch of other fixes, so have to work through that again :( but thnx anyhow - seems easier than before :)

Comment: just one question? how to get the bottom border of the current 'tab' white so it looks like it continues the panel, instead of also having the gray line? for example when you hover over the first tab there is a bottom gray line on the 'tab' part. ?? thnx

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question. Are you saying you want to let the user know what tab they are on?